# VBA Grouping rows based on format

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to group rows based on their formatting in Excel via VBA and, while googling, found a forum post from 2005 where a similar question is asked.
The code that the user posts works great for selecting the rows, but I somehow cannot get the code to actually group the rows.

[Original Forum post](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=39823)

Code:

```
Sub GetSameFormattedRange()  
    Dim c As Range, r As Range, e As Range 
 
    Set e = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Columns(1)) 
 
    SetFormatData 
 
    Set c = e.Find(What:="", SearchFormat:=True) 
 
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 
        Set r = c 
        firstAddress = c.Address 
        Do 
            Set r = Union(r, c) 
            Set c = e.FindNext(After:=c) 
         
            If Not c Is Nothing Then 
                If c.Address = firstAddress Then Exit Do 
            End If 
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing 
    End If 
 
    If Not r Is Nothing Then 
        MsgBox r.Address 
    End If 
 
    Application.FindFormat.Clear 
End Sub 

Sub SetFormatData() 
    Application.FindFormat.Clear 
    Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed 
 
    Application.FindFormat.Locked = True 
    Application.FindFormat.FormulaHidden = False 
End Sub
```

In my case `Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed` will be `Application.FindFormat.IndentLevel = 1`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not work for you, but I was actually doing something similar earlier today, where I grouped items based on .Interior.Pattern, which should also work for .Interior.Color:

```
Dim i as Integer
For i = 2 to 10
    If Cells(i,1).Interior.Pattern=xlSolid Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Group
        Else
        End If
    Next i
```

The caveat to this is that each row becomes grouped, and if the row the subsequent row also groups, then they're paired together, increasing the total length of grouped rows.  if there's a break, it starts a new grouping.

Comment: Works great! Had to tweak it a bit, but thanks a lot for the answer. Spend hours trying to find a far more complicated way to do it.